# How to replace std::shared_ptr with expiring std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-asio, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

I'm working on Asynchronous networking code for use in a library, and my code designed to 'send' data works pretty flawlessly:

```
//connection_id is a wrapper around a size_t
//data_vector is an alias for std::vector<unsigned char>
bool write_to_connection(const connection_id & id, const data_vector & data) {
    if (connections.contains(id)) {
        std::shared_ptr<data_vector> write_buffer = std::make_shared<data_vector>(data);
        connection_ptr conn = connections[id];
        conn->get_socket().async_write_some(
            boost::asio::buffer(
                *write_buffer
                ),
            std::bind(
                &basic_server::write,
                this,
                std::placeholders::_1,
                std::placeholders::_2,
                id,
                write_buffer
            )
        );
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void write(const boost::system::error_code & ec, size_t bytes_written, const connection_id & id, std::shared_ptr<data_vector> write_buffer) {
    if (ec) {
        connections.erase(id);
    }
}
```

However, for performance reasons, I don't like the use of `std::shared_ptr` to maintain my data, especially since I might be issuing many, many of these callbacks at once. I don't even use it in the callback function, and only add it to ensure that the data buffer's lifetime lasts until the write completes.

I'd like to use `std::unique_ptr`, since I only logically need one copy of the object at any given time, which gets passed along (read: *moved*) to the callback function, which I've written like this:

```
//connection_id is a wrapper around a size_t
//data_vector is an alias for std::vector<unsigned char>
bool write_to_connection(const connection_id & id, const data_vector & data) {
    if (connections.contains(id)) {
        std::unique_ptr<data_vector> write_buffer = std::make_unique<data_vector>(data);
        connection_ptr conn = connections[id];
        conn->get_socket().async_write_some(
            boost::asio::buffer(
                *write_buffer
                ),
            std::bind(
                &basic_server::write,
                this,
                std::placeholders::_1,
                std::placeholders::_2,
                id,
                std::move(write_buffer) //So that we're not performing a copy; we're performing a move
            )
        );
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void write(const boost::system::error_code & ec, size_t bytes_written, const connection_id & id, std::unique_ptr<data_vector> write_buffer) {
    if (ec) {
        connections.erase(id);
    }
}
```

However, this promptly gives me this (quite verbose) compile error:

```
Error   C2280   'std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,void (__cdecl server::basic_server::* )(const boost::system::error_code &,size_t,const server::connection_id &,std::unique_ptr<server::data_vector,std::default_delete<_Ty>>),server::basic_server *const ,const std::_Ph<1> &,const std::_Ph<2> &,const server::connection_id &,std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>::_Binder(const std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,void (__cdecl server::basic_server::* )(const boost::system::error_code &,size_t,const server::connection_id &,std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>),server::basic_server *const ,const std::_Ph<1> &,const std::_Ph<2> &,const server::connection_id &,std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function Send File To Server C:\Users\rengland\Workspace_CPP\Library\Includes\boost\asio\basic_stream_socket.hpp 729
```

I'm assuming that it's complaining because the code thinks I'm trying to copy the `std::unique_ptr`, despite my intent being to move it into the callback function. Is there anything I can do to fix this issue, or should I just resign myself to using the `std::shared_ptr` version?

Comment: is c++14 an option? You can move a unique_ptr into a lambda, though the syntax to do so wasn't available till c++14 (I believe)

Comment: @vu1p3n0x I'm using Visual Studio 2015, so it should be c++14 compatible. I'm not sure how that gets around the issue though; is `move`ing into a lambda semantically different than `move`ing into a binder?

Comment: try to make `write` take the unique pointer by reference

Comment: @vu1p3n0x In what way? by using `std::ref`, or simply feeding it a reference? Because the latter will fail when the `std::unique_ptr` goes out of scope at the end of the function.

Comment: No, `void write(..., std::unique_ptr<data_vector>& write_buffer)` leave the move

Comment: @vu1p3n0x That worked for the (relatively simple) tests I performed, but does it guarantee that `write_buffer` doesn't get deleted when `write_to_connection` exits?

Comment: yes, the pointer is moved into what `std::bind` returns. And the function is called with the stored pointer.

Comment: Imagining that using a unique_ptr over a shared_ptr will increase performance is a false premise. The buffering and network transmissions will consume tens of orders of magnitude more time.

Comment: @richardhodges good to know.